# Looking for a Regex which can find all the number combinaitions without having 3 zero's in between and mixed with delimeters

Tags: python-3.x, regex, numbers

I would like to find all the number combinaitions without having 3 zero's in between.
There might be some delimiters (max 2 characters) in between the numbers.
I'm using python and I would like to perform this search with the regex.

Accepted numbers

```
This is number 1234 which should be accepted.
12-45
1 2 0 0  3 4 5
```

not accepted numbers:

```
1
12
123
1000
1000-2000
30000-31000
21 000-32 000-50 000
21 00 03 00 00
```

The regex with which I could come up is:

```
([\s\-]{0,2}\d(?!000)){4,}
```

My regex can find all the accepted numbers but it doesn't filter out all the excepted numbers.

[See the results in regex](https://regex101.com/r/7qo5Hx/2)

Actually this regex is used in python to remove the matched numbers from the text:
[See python code](https://onlinegdb.com/rkthJv7aw)

p.s.   Delimiters are not only space but should be at least \s and dash.

p.s.s. The numbers might be in the middle of the string. So I think I cannot use ^ and $ in my regex.

Comment: What are all the accepted delimiters?

Comment: Try `^(?:[1-9 -]|(?<!0)0(?!0))+$` https://regex101.com/r/7qo5Hx/1

Comment: Or try `^(?!.*0(?:[\s-]{0,2}0){2})[0-9\s-]+$`, see https://regex101.com/r/1GUuVv/1

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen The delimiters are not the point of discussion here but I use \s and also \- for the delimeters

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew and Thefourthbird: Thanks for the response but I'm afraid those regex are not working for me. I updated the question and add more information and test cases.

Comment: This looks rather unwieldly now: `(?<![^-\s])(?!(?:\d(?:[\s-]{0,2}\d)*?)?0(?:[\s-]{0,2}0){2})[0-9](?:[\s-]{0,2}[0-9]){3,}(?![^-\s])`, see https://regex101.com/r/6fgemU/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could assert not 3 zeroes in a row while matching optional delimiters in between.

```
\b(?![\d\s-]*?0(?:[\s-]*0){2})\d(?:[\s-]*\d){3,}\b
```

**Explanation**

- `\b` A word boundary
- `(?!` Negative lookahead, assert what is at the right is not

  - `[\d\s-]*?` Match any of a digit, whitespace char or - as least as possible
  - `0(?:[\s-]*0){2}` - `)` Match a zere followed by 2 times a zero with optional delimiters in between
- `\d` Match a digit
- `(?:[\s-]*\d){3,}` Repeat 3 or more times matching a digit with optional delimiters in between
- `\b` A word boundary

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xN2SYU/1)

Comment: It works in most cases but a few issues: 1. I don't want using ^ and $ because the numbers might be in the middle of the text 2. I added \s instead of space in the delimiters and also remove ^ and $. and it removes only two extra zero from the accepted numbers

Comment: BTW a simple python script and links (following your link) was added to my original question :)

Comment: it also removes all the numbers with length less than 4 digits. I added this test numbers to the original question as well

Comment: @HmT Try it like this `\b(?=[ -]*\d)(?![\d -]*?0(?:[ -]*0){2})\d(?:[  -]*\d){2,}\b`
      https://regex101.com/r/NLFyjG/1

Comment: yes much better but still it captures the 3 digits. I updated the test cases: https://regex101.com/r/NLFyjG/2

Comment: @HmT you could increase the quantifier https://regex101.com/r/d0CQnn/1